# What happens if I imbue basic_stream<char> with locale with codecvt_utf16<char> facet?

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-16, facet, codecvt

Is it specified what will happen if I imbue `basic_stream<char>` with locale with `codecvt_utf16<char>` facet?

Basically, I use `typedef wchar_t tchar;` and `typedef char tchar;` to alter interfaces for (what I call) Unicode and non-Unicode builds of my library. I want to make the source simpler by always imbuing my file streams with locale with `codecvt_utf16<tchar>` facet. Will this work anyhow at all?

(I would not mind if the file read by such imbued `fstream` would have to contain either only ASCII or only code points representable in current global locale.)

**EDIT:**

Given that `codecvt_utf16<char>` seems to be unspecified behaviour, what about imbuing basic_stream with `codecvt_utf16<wchar_t>`? Is this behaviour specified?

Comment: Where did you get the codecvt_utf16? This is normal behavior (imbuing streams) so I don't quite understand the question. Note: you should imbue the file before opening/using the stream otherwise the imbue call will (may) silently be ignored.

Comment: @Martin: I suppose the question should be tagged c++11. There is `std::codecvt_utf16` there.

Comment: @Martin: Do you have reference specifying that behaviour?

Comment: @wilx: No I have no reference only experience with trying to solve a problem that was caused by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per C++0x, `codecvt_utf*<>` can be instantiated with wide characters only. What happens if you use `char` is not specified, the only way to know is to try.

Bear in mind that codecvt_utf16 converts to/from external UTF-16 representation. That is, your file is supposed to be encoded in UTF-16. You might want to consider using UTF-8 instead.

As a side note, it is a mystery to me why would anyone want anything non-Unicode these days. Do people enjoy using restricted character sets or what?

Comment: If it's not specified, it's undefined behaviour, and trying it will likely eat your children :)

Comment: @n.m.: This is for best effort backwards compatibility. I agree that any new application should be UNICODE aware.

Comment: DNS names and most client/server TCP protocol is specified in terms of 7-bit ASCII. Using Unicode would be a waste of time for that.

Comment: It seems that the **can be instantiated with wide characters only** has support in the standard draft I have. Thanks you, I am accepting this answer.